# Show rows with only the highest values in a group

Tags: sql

I have a table with a number of columns but i am trying to group values and only show results where the value in the second columns is the highest.
e.g.

```
ColumnA     ColumnB
Jones       1
Jones       1
Jones       1
Jones       2
Jones       2
Jones       3
Jones       3
Jones       3
Smith       1
Smith       1
Smith       2
Smith       2
Smith       2
```

I have already tried Grouping, Row_Number() Over(Partition By), MAX functions all with no success

I want the output to only show

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
Jones       3
Jones       3
Jones       3
Smith       2
Smith       2
Smith       2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT ColA, ColB
 FROM YourTable t1
 WHERE ColB = (SELECT MAX(colB) FROM YourTable t2 WHERE t1.ColA = t2.ColA)
```

If you want use window function use `RANK()`:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (SELECT ColA, ColB, 
              RANK() OVER 
                (PARTITION ColA ORDER BY ColB DESC) as rn
       FROM YourTable)
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply your first solutiom worked perfectly but i will also try your second option when i return to the office

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT t1.ColumnA,
       t1.ColumnB
FROM   MyTable t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   MyTable t2
                   WHERE  t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
                     AND  t2.ColumnB > t1.ColumnB);
```

Comment: Thank you Robert for your reply i will try this as well when i return to office as its good to have different options for future use